# Powershell - combine switch statement and loop

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have a piece of code presented below, it takes values from a json file. This is a array of string --> `$Json.Names`. I would like to avoid duplicate lines like --> `$Json.Names[0].Name  {$Json.Names[0].Name; break}`. Second case is that Array `$Json.Names` could have different length, array can have 6 and more or less elements. I want to make this switch statement more elastic. I tried to use `for loop` and `while loop`, but in this case these loops doesn't help me. Is there any clever method to make this code more sophisticated/elastic and avoid duplicate mentioned code lines`$Json.Names[0].Name  {$Json.Names[0].Name; break}`

```
$Json = Get-Content "$path" | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json
$Name = switch ($Member) {
    $Json.Names[0].Name  {$Json.Names[0].Name; break}
    $Json.Names[1].Name  {$Json.Names[1].Name; break}
    $Json.Names[2].Name  {$Json.Names[2].Name; break}
    $Json.Names[3].Name  {$Json.Names[3].Name; break}
    $Json.Names[4].Name  {$Json.Names[4].Name; break}
    $Json.Names[5].Name  {$Json.Names[5].Name; break}
    $Json.Names[6].Name  {$Json.Names[6].Name; break}
    default {"Unknown Name"}
}
```

Comment: `$Json.Names.Name |Where {$_ -like $member}`

Comment: What does the json look like?  Switch *is* a loop:  `switch (1..5) { $_ { $_ } } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of property enumeration and simplify your code pretty significantly:

```
# define our default
$Name = "Unknown Name"

# define the list of names 
$Json = Get-Content "$path" | ConvertFrom-Json
$Names = $Json.Names.Name

# update $Name if applicable
if($Names -contains $member){
    $Name = $member
}
```

Comment: Thx, it helps me, tested pipeline, and it works, similar solution to this proposed by @js2010

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this structure:

```
$json = [pscustomobject]@{names = [pscustomobject]@{name ='joe'},
  [pscustomobject]@{name ='john'},
  [pscustomobject]@{name ='james'}}
```

Assuming $member is a single name, you can say

```
$name = $json.names.name -eq $member # an array of one
```

$name would be a null array if there's no match.

```
if (! $name) { $name = 'Unknown Name' }
```

Or, in the language of Powershell 7 preview 5:

```
$name ??= 'Unknown Name'
```

You also may want to make a hashtable of the names.